# How to call Akka Http POST in loop (1000-10000 times)?

Tags: java, akka-http

I am learning Akka with Java. I have written a simple program with two actors.

My first actor **ActorA** is called with list containing 1000 strings. **ActorA** loops through the list and calls **ActorB** for each element.

**ActorB** makes a Http POST call to external service using the String parameter received from **ActorA**.

I am expecting that **ActorB** will successfully make 1000 Http POST calls and will receive equal number of responses. However **ActorB** is able to make POST request randomly between 80-120 times then it stops making POST calls.

I tried providing a custom dispatcher as HTTP POST call is a blocking operation but still no luck!!

Refer to code and configuration given below.

```
public class ActorA extends AbstractActor {
static public Props props() {
    return Props.create(ActorA.class);
}


static public class IdWrapper {
    List<String> ids;

    public IdWrapper(List<String> ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }
}


@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
            .match(IdWrapper.class, this::process)
            .build();
}

private void process(IdWrapper msg) {
    msg.ids.forEach(id -> {
        context().actorSelection("actorB").tell(new MessageForB(id), ActorRef.noSender());
        }
    );
}
```

}

```
public class ActorB extends AbstractActor {   

final Http http = Http.get(getContext().system());
final Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(context());    

public static Props props() {
    return Props.create(ActorB.class);
}

static public class MessageForB implements Serializable {
    String id;

    public MessageForB(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}


@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
            .match(MessageForB.class, this::process)
            .build();
}

private void process(MessageForB messageForB) {

    ExecutionContext ec = getContext().getSystem().dispatchers().lookup("my-blocking-dispatcher");
    /**
     * Get id from request
     */
    String reqId = messageForB.id;

    /**
     * Prepare request
     */
    XmlRequest requestEntity = getRequest(Stream.of(reqId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    String requestAsString = null;


    try {
        /**
         * Create and configure JAXBMarshaller.
         */
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlRequest.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

        /**
         * Convert request entity to string before making POST request.
         */
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(requestEntity, sw);
        requestAsString = sw.toString();

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Create RequestEntity from request string.
     */
    RequestEntity entity = HttpEntities.create(
            MediaTypes.APPLICATION_XML.toContentType(HttpCharsets.ISO_8859_1),
            requestAsString);

    /**
     * Create Http POST with necessary headers and call
     */
    final CompletionStage<HttpResponse> responseFuture =
            http.singleRequest(HttpRequest.POST("http://{hostname}:{port}/path")
                    .withEntity(entity));

    responseFuture
            .thenCompose(httpResponse -> {
                /**
                 * Convert response into String
                 **/
                final CompletionStage<String> res = Unmarshaller.entityToString().unmarshal
                        (httpResponse.entity(), ec, materializer);
                /**
                 * Consume response bytes
                 **/
                httpResponse.entity().getDataBytes().runWith(Sink.ignore(), materializer);
                return res;

            })
            .thenAccept(s -> {

                try {
                    /**
                     * Deserialize string to DTO.
                     */
                    MyResponse MyResponse = getMyResponse(s);

                    // further processing..

                } catch (JAXBException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}

private XmlRequest getRequest(List<String> identifiers){
    XmlRequest request = new XmlRequest();
    // Business logic to create req entity
    return request;
}

    private MyResponse getMyResponse(String s) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance
            (MyResponse.class);
    javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext
            .createUnmarshaller();
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(s);
    return (MyResponse)
            jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
}
```

}

```
my-blocking-dispatcher {
type = Dispatcher
executor = "thread-pool-executor"
thread-pool-executor {
core-pool-size-min = 5
core-pool-size-max = 20
}
throughput = 1
}
```

Where can I improve or correct my code so that **ActorB** will successfully be able to make Http POST calls for all the items sent by **ActorA** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see you have used `http.singleReques`.

According to the [akka-http docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/request-level.html)

> For these cases Akka HTTP offers the Http().singleRequest(...) method, which simply turns an HttpRequest instance into Future[HttpResponse]. Internally the request is dispatched across the (cached) host connection pool for the request’s effective URI.

`http.singleRequest` uses connection pool to handle requests so you need to increase number of connections in connection pool from akka http [config](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html).

in host-connection-pool section with this defaults:

```
host-connection-pool {
  max-connections = 4
  min-connections = 0
  max-retries = 5
  max-open-requests = 32
  pipelining-limit = 1
  idle-timeout = 30 s
}
```

**Solution 2 :**

using [http.outgoingConnection](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/connection-level.html)

according to the [akka-http docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/connection-level.html#connection-level-client-side-api) it will be create an specific connection per request. So you can handle 1000 connections in parallel without connection pool.

> With the connection-level API you open a new HTTP connection to a target endpoint by materializing a Flow returned by the Http().outgoingConnection(...) method. Here is an example:

```
def run(req:String): Unit ={
  val apiBaseUrl = "example.com" //without protocol
  val path = "/api/update"
  val body = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`,req.getBytes)
  val request = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, path,entity = body)
  val connectionFlow = Http().outgoingConnection(apiBaseUrl)
  val result =   Source.single(request).via(connectionFlow).runWith(Sink.head)
  result.onComplete{
    case Success(value) =>
      println(value)
    case Failure(e)=>
      e.printStackTrace()
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hamed, I think you missed to provide link to  example. Can you please provide it?

Comment: Hi @GurunathSolanki, sample added.